# HTTPOnly cookie not available in getServerSideProps on Next JS

Tags: javascript, cookies, next.js, httponly

The following `HTTPOnly` cookie `did` is not available in `getServerSideProps` using `Next JS`:

[image]

The `jid` cookie is set by an `Expressjs` API located at the url `https://api-dev.example.com`
I am tried to get the cookie from an Next JS app located at the url `https://localhost:3000`.

In other words, the API is online but trying to get the cookie on `localhost`.

The `getServerSideProps` method used:

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
    console.log(ctx.req.headers.cookie);

    return {
        props: {},
    };
};
```

Here is what is printed in the console:

```sh
_ga=GA1.1.1479601312.1604335288; 
_gid=GA1.1.1556520191.1604335288; 
_gat_gtag_...._1=1; 
_nid=ey...Cn0drV6-ImMPY
```

The cookie printed all have a domain `localhost` and are not `HTTPOnly`.

Any insights?

Comment: Cookie are not send cross S-domain. So you will not be able to read a cookie set from another domain. Other I'ill make an app to read your cookies from gmail, facebook, ...

Comment: so based on what you are saying I am not able to get that value if I want to use it for SSR authentication?

Comment: No, you're not able to read cookie from another domain, that's all I said. Work on the same domain and everything will work.

Comment: Yes that is what I understood but it starts to be cumbersome while working locally on the client side with an API already in place. So all code written on the client side must be deployed before even testing that it works.

Comment: Is there a solution for the local development problem, having you frontend running on localhost and your api on a different domain with http only cookies?

Comment: i have the same issue and didn't find a solution yet, all works fine if on the same domain, when i switch backend to another domain cookie is not read.
But the weird part is that i am using useMutation and use Query with apolloClient, when in production/development they send the cookie, but if i manually use the client in getServerSideProps cookie is not present!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like cookie is set at https://api-dev.example.com and you are trying to access it on localhost. you cannot read cookie from a different domain due to security reasons.

If you cannot setup api on your localhost. One workaround would be to add a host entry on your local system. Add below entry in your hosts file

`localhost http://ui-dev.example.com`

This will enable you to access your localhost using `http://ui-dev.example.com:3000` and the cookie set on `example.com` will be accessible locally.